# How do I disable a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am working on a project in which I have to show all photos of Photo Library in a plist and show them horizontally on `UIButton`s.

My app will also have an edit button: when the user clicks this button, a delete mark (such as usually appears in other iPhone/iPad apps) should show on each button.

But here's the crucial bit: as soon as this delete mark appears, the functionality of the button should be disabled. I've tried accomplishing this with the following:

```
{
  editbutton.enabled=NO;
}
```

...but it neither produces an error nor works. What should I do?

Comment: Show the code block where you did disable

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Please set this...

```
 editButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

or You can use

```
 editButton.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use this, setEnabled:NO would be the proper way to to it which would update the UI as well.

Comment: what's the diff between 'isEnabled' and 'enabled'

Comment: @OMGPOP isEnabled is a synthesized getter for enabled property.

Comment: enabled has been renamed to isEnabled in Swift 3 iOS 10

Comment: In iOS 10 Swift 3, isEnabled is the only thing present. setEnabled is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 3 and above

`editButton.isEnabled = false`

`setEnabled` is now part of the setter method for `isEnabled`.

Answer (score 8):

setter for property **enabled** is overridden in class **UIButton.** try to send a message.

```
 [editbutton setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `enabled` property of `UIControl` which the super class of `UIButton` and set it with NO.

**myButton.enabled = NO;**

You could also try as **@Marvin** suggested,
In that case your button will not respond to any touch event from user,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above:

Set
`editButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
or you can use
`editButton.enabled = NO;`

You might want to gray out the button so the user knows it was disabled:
`editButton.alpha = 0.66`

Answer (score 0):

```
yourBtn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```