# Only allow users to press UIButton once

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to design a interface of an app, and i would only like to allow the user to press a UIButton once to get the result. Is there any way i can lock the button after the button is pressed? And release the lock only when another button is pressed?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210850/how-do-i-disable-a-uibutton

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the button to be disabled once it is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    //See all buttons enabled
    //Try a loop or manually

    ((UIButton *)sender).enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Just use the property `enabled` of the UIButton. When the user presses it, set enabled to NO: `[myButton setEnabled:NO];`, and set `YES` when you need enable it again later.

Answer (score 2):

This is the updated version of James Paolantonio's answer for Swift 4

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    //See all buttons enabled
    //Try a loop or manually
    (sender as? UIButton)?.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the Uibutton when your selector method for the button is called.
as in [aButton setEnabled:False];, and when the user taps the other button reenable the first one and disable the second one as in [bButton setEnabled:False] and [aButton setEnabled:True],

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the first pressed button.. on the next press you can enable the old one and disable the new one

```
Button *disabledButton;
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {        
   if (disabledButton)
     disabledButton.enabled = YES;

   disabledButton = ((UIButton *)sender);
   disabledButton.enabled = NO;
 }
```