# How to disable a UI control in Xamarin Mac (MonoMac)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

Recently I've just started to learn using Xamarin and I made a tiny demo Mac app with Cocoa UI stuff for fun. Now I need to disable, and then re-enable a button on my app, I've search for a while and I've found this: [How do I disable a UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210850/how-do-i-disable-a-uibutton)

But this article seems only works on iOS platform, there is no any references/methods on Xamarin.Mac. So I would like to know how to disable and enable the UI control on this platform.

Thanks and Regards,
Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NSButton` as an `Enabled` property to enable/disable the control:

```
partial void EnableDisable(NSButton sender)
{
    EnableDisableBtn.Enabled = !EnableDisableBtn.Enabled;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoMac.AppKit.NSControl.Enabled/

Example:

```
var button = new NSButton(new CGRect(40, 40, 50, 40));
button.Enabled = true;
button.Activated += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    (sender as NSButton).Enabled = false;
};
View.AddSubview(button);
```

Comment: Hello, I've double-checked but I couldn't find any property called "Enabled" in my button. Did I misunderstand something??

Comment: @JacksonMingHu I added another example to the answer; `NSButton.Enabled`

Comment: Thanks. I've got a mistake when I drag the button in Xcode. I've selected something wrong as it was set to NSObject, not NSButton. Now it works!