# Disable UIButton after button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, event-handling

I'm working on a project, I have a requirement of disabling the `UIButton` after  button is clicked or pressed.

TIA

Comment: On your action:@selector method, hide/disable the button.

Comment: What you have tried show your coding

Comment: Abhimanyu brother try my answer.It works what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable a UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210850/how-do-i-disable-a-uibutton)

Answer (score 2):

On your `Button` action method set `enabled` of `Button` to `NO`.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender {    
    sender.enabled = NO; // With disabled style on button 
    //If you doesn't want disabled style on button use this.
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: it directly disable button, but my requirement is after it's first click the button should be disabled

Comment: Thats why i written on button action, check my answer properly. Button action method only call when you perform its specific action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
-(void)buttonOnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.enabled = NO;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by two ways:

```
Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

or use:

```
Button.enabled = NO;
```

Like,

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(UIButton*)sender {    
    sender.enabled = NO;
    //OR
    //sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

It will be good to go with `setEnabled:NO` because, it is proper way to do it and it will also update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can set false for enabled property like below.

**Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)btnNextClicked:(UIButton *)sender {    
    sender.enabled = NO; 
}
```

**Swift**

```
@IBAction func btnNextClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you first click or when you try to click second time it does not enable.I set the condition.I save the first click value into NSUserdefault.I tried sample and it works fine.

```
- (IBAction)actionGoPrevious:(id)sender
{
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSInteger btnFirstClick = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"firstClick"];
   if(btnFirstClick == 1){
    btnBack.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        //OR
    btnBack.enabled = NO;
  }
  else{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"firstClick"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: then what about  **exclusiveTouch** option